# Modifying one leg of round trip ticket

Tags: transit, tickets, return

Not too sure of this is possible, or if the only solution for this issue is actually booking multi-city single tickets however here’s a shot...

So my plan is to fly from London to Dubai on Aeroflot via Moscow, hoewever, on the return from Dubai, I’d like to spend a day or two in Moscow and the longest transit in Moscow I could find was around 15 hours. I’d like to spend at least a day or two there if possible.

Can this be done with one booking/ticket?

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky you can add a "stopover" with almost no additional cost. Look at a the bunch of round trips and then read the "fare rules" before you book. The "fare rules" is a lot of technical language that you need to agree to when booking but that rarely anyone reads. It spells out exactly what happens for changes, delays, cancellations, over booking, solar eclipses, and of course "stopovers".

"Stopover" is the term you want to search for. It's going to say something like "permitted", "not permitted", "permitted for $100 each" or something to this extent. If it says "permitted", than you are golden. Try to book it as the thee city trip online and if it doesn't show up (which is possible), call the airline and ask them to specifically book it as a "round trip with Stop over". If stopovers are not permitted or too expensive you can also try booking a higher fare class for the initial ticket: $50 more upfront may result in a free stop over.

That's all a bit of work, but can be very cost effective: I'm currently on a 7 city itinerary that was booked as an open jaw round trip with 4 stopovers and the price is only 5% more than a simple round trip would have been.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common options for what you describe are

1. A Multi-city Itinerary (1 booking with 3 segments, not 3 separate bookings)
2. A Stopover on a round-trip

What's the difference?  Not much if anything.

A Stopover is in practice a multi-city itinerary that is sold as a special fare allowing travelers to visit (usually) a hub city of the airline for less than the cost than 3 segments would be otherwise.

You can inquire if Aeroflot offers such a deal, such as part of a vacation package*, then compare the price to a regular multi-city itinerary.

*Meaning, it's quite possible this option will not show up in the regular booking engine, rather as a special offer or through a different part of the web site.

Note, this presumes you want to stick with Aeroflot.  You may get a better deal booking separate tickets using Travelocity/Expedia/Etc.

Comment: Sometimes airlines will offer discounted hotel rooms to encourage stopovers in their country.